# call a Javascript function from ascx page code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using the below client script to pass a value to a javascript function. It works fine in an aspx page but in an ascx page it, is not working. Please help me to solve this.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "tabmvng", "<script language='javascript'>SetActiveTab(3); </script>", false);
```

Comment: It helps a lot if you tell us what is not working, rather than expecting people to guess it.

Answer (score 5):

Try this, It is all because UserControl, you are no longer dealing with a Page.

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, typeof(UpdatePanel), UniqueID, "myFunction('" + parameter + "');", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function SetActiveTab(a){
alert(a);
}
</script>

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "tabmvng", "SetActiveTab(3);", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Control Caller = this; //user control
string MyScript= "SetActiveTab(3);";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Caller, typeof(Caller), "Script Name", MyScript), true);
```

Get through Script manager having trouble adding scripts to the Page object from that user control use a reference to the calling user control.  In addition, it will wrap the script for you so no need to add the script tag.

EDIT NOTE: I assume this function exists in your script somewhere: `SetActiveTab(3);`

Answer (score 0):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(System.Web.UI.Page), "javascript", "YourScript", true);
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue of the Javascript not being in the html output. Turns out if you are doing this from ascx (control) you have to pass reference to the control, in example **Me**.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), jscript, True)
```

After that, all started to work! thanks Mark Schultheiss!